# Clarify theta parameter in statistical modeling for probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

[image]

I understand the $f_n(x_1,…,x_n|\theta)$ and $X_1,…,X_n$ statements but what confuses me is the part about the unknown parameters $\theta = (\theta_1,…,\theta_k)^T$  .

**Is there set of parameters, $\theta$, unique to each instance of $x_i$ in $X$?** 
Or does each instance of theta correlate with a unique $x_i$ in $X?$ (If so, why is $k$ used instead of $n$ [I don't think this is the case])

**Is this a general definition that applies to scalar and vector instances of $\theta$?**

If this was a $gamma$ distrubution, I would assume that each instance of $\theta$ would be a vector of 2 values (i.e. $\alpha$, $\beta$) or if it was a gaussian distribution, it would be a mean and standard deviation.  Is this correct?

Comment: this is only a model, in real life measured datas never follow exactly a gaussian distribution, but if you suppose it, you can search for the mean and variance which best fit the observed datas. so $f(x_i | \theta)$ must be read as "the probability to observe $X_i = x_i$ supposing $X_i$ is a random variable drawn from a given distribution $f$ with parameters $\theta$ "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. This definition means that X is a random variable that depends on $\bf{\theta}=(\theta_1, ..., \theta_k)$. And $x_1, ..., x_n$ are n independent draws from the random variable $X$

Let me give you an example, if X is normal distributed, then $\theta = (\mu, \sigma^2)$ would be the parameter vector of $X$. You can draw as many samples from this normal distribution as you like, and these samples are all identically distributed by $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$